# Kable doesn't render a model that printed

Tags: r, kable

Basically the statistics and the functions here don't matter as much. I cannot share the data itself so i tried to keep the original functions. Printing worked well with Cat or Print, But r markdown refuses to work well.

This is a way simpler and reproducible example than posted before.

````
    ---
    title: "test"
    output: html_document
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ## R Markdown


    ```{r printing, results='asis', echo= FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(haven)
    library(foreign)
    library(mfx)
    library(jtools)
    library(skimr)
    library(kableExtra)


    frml <- "mpg ~ wt"

    ##glm formula
      model1 <- mtcars %>% glm(data=., frml, family = "poisson")

    ##IRR for poisson
      model2<- mtcars %>% poissonirr(formula = frml, robust = T)

    ##Printing inside a formula 
    kbl <- function (df) {
        kable(df) %>% 
        kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")) }


    print_model <- function (df1, df2) {
      kbl(df1)
      kbl(df2) }

      print_model(model1,model2)
````

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you set the chunk option `include = FALSE`?

Comment: Ive edited it into `echo=FALSE`

Comment: Hi @Stat.Enthus. Could you be a bit more specific what the issue is? Just checked by simply printing mtcars and iris, i.e `print_model(mtcars, iris)` and it works well. As expected it prints a table of the iris dataset.

Comment: Did you check it with Rmarkdown? My issue is that printing of this glm model works well in console, but not in Rmarkdown. Since Glm models are less common, I am trying to figure out why is that. I have tried using summ function to view them

Comment: Yep. Rendered the Rmd. And got a nice table in the html. But I will have a look at the code including your model.

Comment: This prints well in console but doesn't render in knit, for example `t<- summ(model1)
print_model(t$coeftable, t$model)`

Comment: The issue is that your models are no dfs. You have to convert the model output to a dataframe. In case of model1 this could ne easily done using `broom` package, e.g. try `broom::tidy(model1`). However, there is no standard method in broom for the second kind of modell

Comment: Thanks. This is a challenge as i have not seen other methods of extracting this calculation in R (other packages)

Comment: I ended up using parts of this unprintable model for Kable. Thanks!!